# How to ask STUN server to generate the ice candidates using aiortc?

Tags: python, webrtc, aiortc

I have a working WebRTC client, and I want to receive it's video via WebRTC using aiotrc (python). The other client is working fine as the recipient, we have tested it with a browser.

Using python, I configure the server, I create an offer with a Transceiver (I only want to receive the video), and I set the offer as the localDescription:

```
import json
import socketio
import asyncio
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from aiortc import RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription, RTCIceCandidate, RTCConfiguration, RTCIceServer, RTCIceGatherer, RTCRtpTransceiver

session_id = 'default'

sio = socketio.Client()

ice_server = RTCIceServer(urls='stun:stun.l.google.com:19302')
pc = RTCPeerConnection(configuration=RTCConfiguration(iceServers=[ice_server]))

pc.addTransceiver("video", direction="recvonly")

def connect():
    sio.connect('https://192.168.10.123', namespaces=['/live'])

connect()

@async_to_sync
async def set_local_description():
    await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createOffer())
    print('Local description set to: ', pc.localDescription)
    #send_signaling_message(json.dumps({'sdp':{'sdp': pc.localDescription.sdp, 'type':pc.localDescription.type}}))


set_local_description()
```

(Where the socket.io is connecting is a fake address in this case). After this point, I have no idea how to gather the ice candidates. I have tried using the iceGatherer with no luck:

```
ice_gath = RTCIceGatherer(iceServers=[ice_server])
candidates = ice_gath.getLocalCandidates()
```

I have to send the ice candidate to the recipient. At this point I couldn't find any information about, how to get the ice candidates using aiortc. What is the next step?

Answer (score 4):

The code you posted has in fact already performed the ICE candidate gathering, when you called `setLocalDescription`. Look at the session description you are printing and you should see candidates marked as `srflx` which means "server reflexive": these are your IP addresses as seen from the STUN server's perspective, e.g:

```
a=candidate:5dd630545cbb8dd4f09c40b43b0f2db4 1 udp 1694498815 PUBLIC.IP.ADDRESS.HERE 42162 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.44 rport 42162
```

Also note that by default `aiortc` already uses Google's STUN server, so here is an even more reduced version of your example:

```py
import asyncio

from aiortc import RTCPeerConnection


async def dump_local_description():
    pc = RTCPeerConnection()
    pc.addTransceiver("video", direction="recvonly")

    await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createOffer())
    print(pc.localDescription.sdp)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(dump_local_description())
```